# Bidirectional communiation with websockets in Quart

Tags: websocket, async-await, python-asyncio, quart

I want to be able to use a WebSocket in Quart to receive any messages that are sent, and send any messages that I may need to send. There's no guarantee that messages will alternate between sending and receiving.

As an example, [Quart's tutorial page on WebSockets](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/tutorials/websocket_tutorial.html#broadcasting) features the following snippet:

```
@app.websocket('/api/v2/ws')
@collect_websocket
async def ws(queue):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send(data)
```

Somehow, I want to modify the code in the `while True` loop so that I can check if there is any data to be received, but if there isn't, I will instead check the queue.

I would like to be able to await receiving on the socket only if there is something to receive (which maybe could be achieved if there were a `timeout` parameter in the `receive` method), but that is not an option.

So, **how can I `await` a WebSocket for updates while also `await`ing something else for updates**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of Quart answers this in the post [Websockets in Quart](https://medium.com/@pgjones/websockets-in-quart-f2067788d1ee), which contains a snippet which I've modified slightly to get the following:

```py
import asyncio

from quart import copy_current_websocket_context, Quart, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.websocket('/ws')
async def ws():

    async def consumer():
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive()

    async def producer():
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await websocket.send(b'Message')

    consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer())
    producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer())
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, producer_task)
    finally:
        consumer_task.cancel()
        producer_task.cancel()
```

The snippet creates two different async functions with their own `while True` loops. Then, Python's [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) is used to create two different [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)s to  work on . Finally, `asyncio.gather` is called to evaluate the tasks concurrently.

By defining the two tasks inside the definition of `ws`, they act as closures, meaning they have access to the `websocket` "special" global object, which is only meaningful inside the `ws` function. If you wanted to define these functions outside the body of the `ws` function, perhaps because you need to call them from elsewhere, you could use the [`copy_current_websocket_context`](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/reference/source/quart.html#quart.copy_current_websocket_context) function from Quart when passing them to `ensure_future`:

```
consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(
    copy_current_websocket_context(consumer)()
)
```